# Java Loop parameters are ignored; Loop doesn't break

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, tokenize

I want my input to be a minimum of 4 strings and a maximum of 8. I am tokenizing them for practice. I have parameters set up so that the number of tokens must be over 4 and less than 8, but my code runs no matter the number of tokens and I don't know why.

I have also tried to insert a break at multiple locations and I cannot figure out how to stop it and continue on.  Each time I run it I need to manually terminate it.

I want to get the input, reprint it, list the number of chars in each token, then reevaluate the chars again for upper/lower cases, digits, white spaces.

I really appreciate any insight.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class charEvaluation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> tokenizedInput = new ArrayList<>();
    String sentenceRetrieved;

    // getting the sentence from the user
    System.out.println("Please type a sentence containing at least 4 words, with a maximum of 8 words: ");
    sentenceRetrieved = sc.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sentenceRetrieved);

    
    while (true) {
        while (strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokenizedInput.add(strTokenizer.nextToken());
        int count = strTokenizer.countTokens();
        if (count <= 8 && count >= 4) {
            break;
        }
    }
        

    // printing out the sentence
    System.out.println("You entered: ");
    System.out.println(sentenceRetrieved);


    // count the characters in each word
     int totalLength = 0;

      for (String each : tokenizedInput) {

         totalLength += each.length();
         System.out.println( each + " has " + each.length() + " characters.");
      }
      
         System.out.println("The total number of characters entered without spaces: "+
                    sentenceRetrieved.replace(" ", "").length());
         
         /*
          * Setting up a character array and determining how many
          * letters, digits, lower case letters, upper case letters and white spaces in the input.
          */
         
         char [] array;
         int letters = 0,
             digits = 0,
             lowerCase = 0,
             upperCase = 0,             
             whitespaces = 0;
         
         array = sentenceRetrieved.toCharArray();
         for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(array[i]))
                 letters ++;
            if(Character.isDigit(array[i]))
                digits++;
            else if(Character.isUpperCase(array[i]))
                upperCase++;
            else if(Character.isLowerCase(array[i]))
                lowerCase++;
            else if(Character.isWhitespace(array[i]))
                whitespaces++;
         }
         
        System.out.println("The number of letters is " + letters + ".");
        System.out.println("The number of digits is " + digits + ".");
        System.out.println("The number of lower case letters is " + lowerCase+ ".");
        System.out.println("The number of upper case letters is " + upperCase + ".");
        System.out.println("The number of white spaces is " + whitespaces + ".");

    }
      
}

}
```

My output to console then is a continual loop of the following, before I manually terminate it:

```
You entered: 
hi there
hi has 2 characters.
there has 5 characters.
The total number of characters entered without spaces: 7
The number of letters is 7.
The number of digits is 0.
The number of lower case letters is 7.
The number of upper case letters is 0.
The number of white spaces is 1.
```

All of the information is accurate, but I don't want it to accept a count of less than 4 tokens or more than 8 and I then want it to stop after this output is provided once.

I really appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have to stop your main for loop somehow; the easiest way to fix it is introduce boolean variable that will indicate to the application that loop should be terminated as such:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> tokenizedInput = new ArrayList<>();
    String sentenceRetrieved = "";

    boolean isConditionsMet = false;
    while (!isConditionsMet) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type a sentence containing at least 4 words, with a maximum of 8 words: ");
        sentenceRetrieved = sc.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sentenceRetrieved);
        int count = strTokenizer.countTokens();
        if (count <= 4 || count >= 8) {
            continue;
        } else {
            isConditionsMet = true;
        }

        while (strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokenizedInput.add(strTokenizer.nextToken());
        }
    }

    // printing out the sentence
    System.out.println("You entered: ");
    System.out.println(sentenceRetrieved);

    // count the characters in each w
    int totalLength = 0;

    for (String each : tokenizedInput) {
        totalLength += each.length();
        System.out.println(each + " has " + each.length() + " characters.");
    }

    System.out.println("The total number of characters entered without spaces: " +
            sentenceRetrieved.replace(" ", "").length());

    /*
     * Setting up a character array and determining how many
     * letters, digits, lower case letters, upper case letters and white spaces in the input.
     */

    char[] array;
    int letters = 0,
            digits = 0,
            lowerCase = 0,
            upperCase = 0,
            whitespaces = 0;

    array = sentenceRetrieved.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(array[i]))
            letters++;
        if (Character.isDigit(array[i]))
            digits++;
        else if (Character.isUpperCase(array[i]))
            upperCase++;
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(array[i]))
            lowerCase++;
        else if (Character.isWhitespace(array[i]))
            whitespaces++;
    }

    System.out.println("The number of letters is " + letters + ".");
    System.out.println("The number of digits is " + digits + ".");
    System.out.println("The number of lower case letters is " + lowerCase + ".");
    System.out.println("The number of upper case letters is " + upperCase + ".");
    System.out.println("The number of white spaces is " + whitespaces + ".");
}
```

Also, small note regarding your code - totalLength is never used.

Comment: Thank you.  This helps my loop issue, but do you know why my parameters are ignored?  No matter the number of strings, it prints to the console, but I only want it to be between and  4 and 8 inclusive.

Comment: Oh, the same issue here, when you execute your "break" statement, it existed only inner loop - your second while loop - if you would like to exist the program completely, you should use "return" instead

Comment: There are 2 more issues; firstly, you have to execute countTokens before you call strTokenizer.nextToken(). Secondly, yoru if statement is wrong, it says "execute me if count more then 4 and lesser then 8", but it should be opposite count <= 4 || count >= 8, i.e. only input with 4 or 8 tokens will be accepted, e.g. "hi there" will be rejected

Comment: @ZacharyMull may I know why did you introduce a while loop at first? I don't actually see much value in it; so, I would get rid of it, change condition and use return statement there

Comment: I'm not sure it made sense because I wanted to fill my tokenized input array.   Now that I have placed      tokenizedInput.add(strTokenizer.nextToken()); after int count =  strTokenizer.countTokens(); and flipped my greater than and less than, my only issue is that when the parameters are not met, it still prints and prints the output twice.  If the parameters are met it works perfectly.

Comment: @ZacharyMull that's why you need a return statement to terminate the application execution; another way to tackle it is to put your scanner code inside the loop, so the logic will work as follows: 1. insert your statement;  2. check if your statement is met your requirements (from 4 to 8 tokens); 3. if so, proceed with the valuation 4. if it doesn't met, ask to key in a pharse again

Comment: @ZacharyMull I've changed my answer code to show how the whole thing will work

Comment: Thank you, Alexander.  I really appreciate your time.  I am still having trouble working through some of this logic so when it is shown, I can realize it faster.  I see what you are saying now.  Your logic makes a lot of sense.  I really can't thank you enough for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is marking your infinite outer loop by a label:

```
// your label here.
outerLoop:
while (true) {
    if (..condition..) {
        // this statement will break corresponding marked loop.
        break outerLoop;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the bad and harmful example of using goto. Java has built in mechanisms to exit the cycle and there is not reason to reinvent the wheel and use goto here.

Answer (score -1):

Which IDE are you using ? Do you know what a debugger is ?
Try your code in a debugger.

I think your code is correct but as far as I can see "while is always true". So it runs endless. Just create a boolean and set it to false at the end.

```
if (strTokenizer.countTokens ( ) >= 4 && strTokenizer.countTokens ( ) <= 8) 
            {
                int count = strTokenizer.countTokens ( ); 
                System.out.println (count); 
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println ("Error. Please type a sentence containing at least 4 words, with a maximum of 8 words"); 
                System.exit (1); 
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= strTokenizer.countTokens ( ); i++) 
            {
                tokenizedInput.add (i, strTokenizer.nextToken ( ) ); 
            }

            // printing out the sentence
            System.out.println ("You entered: ");
            System.out.println (sentenceRetrieved);

            // count the characters in each word
            int totalLength = 0;
```

Comment: This should be in a comment.

Comment: This should be in a comment ? Why ?

Comment: Thanks, this helps with the loop, but I am don't know why my parameters are being ignored.

Comment: You aren't providing a viable solution. Saying questions inside an answer is the first notice that should go off.

Comment: Are you serious? Sorry, I did not know that. But I provided an answer.

Comment: So what about rhetorical questions ? xD

Comment: Your code runs no matter the number of tokens you have because strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens() always returns true if there are more elements (strings) left. Just use a for-loop instead.